# Detect HTTPS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, https

I am trying to find how can I detect with JavaScript if I am in a HTTP or HTTPS environment.

I am calling an Ajax request so if I am in HTTPS and call HTTP Ajax then I get a 302 Moved Temporarily.

I was thinking of getting the current `window.location.href` and do a string manipulation.

What is the best way of detecting HTTPS using JavaScript?

Comment: @DanDascalescu did you used "flag" to mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: @HackerKarma: I voted to close three weeks ago. Nothing happened, and only then I used the flag.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thanks. I just flagged it to close. Let's see what happens.

Comment: @HackerKarma: I saw no close votes after reading your comment (looks like mine was removed - I don't understand how or why). I've just voted to close again, and still see "close (1)", which suggests your vote has been removed too? Edit: just noticed your rep is 394. Are you allowed to cast close votes?

Comment: @DanDascalescu sorry I meant to say flagged it as "duplicate"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the non-standard

```
window.location.protocol
```

In Firefox: [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location)

In IE, it seems to be

```
 document.location.protocol
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534353%28VS.85%29.aspx)

I can't find reliable info on how this behaves on other browsers, but I expect they adhere to the quasi-standard of `document.location.protocol`.

Maybe the [jQuery url plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser) sorts this out without having to deal with cross-browser differences - I've never used it myself, but it looks promising:

```
jQuery.url.attr("protocol");
```

Comment: +1: that is more generic way for it :)

Answer (score 63):

Looking at how google analytics add their script to the page:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

Then document.location.protocol would seem safe for all browsers.

Comment: Great insight. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 8):

`location.protocol` works on all browsers.

Comment: There are more than two browsers :)

Answer (score 8):

How about this ?

```
 var protocol = window.location.href.indexOf("https://")==0?"https":"http";
```

Comment: should be protocol = window.location.href.indexOf("https://")==0?"https":"http";

Answer (score 6):

In many instances, one can omit the protocol altogether. So, instead of

```
<img src="https://test.com/image.jpg" />
```

one could use

```
<img src="//test.com/image.jpg" />
```

The browser then adds the current protocol automatically. This also works for including files in the head, and it should also work for ajax calls.

Edit: Doing this is now considered to be an anti-pattern:

> Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn’t have performance concerns, this technique is now an anti-pattern. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then always use the https:// asset.
>
> Allowing the snippet to request over HTTP opens the door for attacks like the recent Github Man-on-the-side attack. It’s always safe to request HTTPS assets even if your site is on HTTP, however the reverse is not true.

see: http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: confirmed this does work for ajax calls... at least with AngularJS `$http.get('//example.com')`

Comment: One caveat I ran into is that this answer won't work after deploying the code to a mobile device (if you're using Cordova  or PhoneGap). In that siutation  // will resolve to file:// so you can never use it for http calls. If you're not developing for mobile, just disregard this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really neat lib called URI for things like this.  https://github.com/medialize/URI.js

You probably don't need this just to grab the protocol, but if you're going to be string manipulating URIs, you should use this.